# Shiny is adding inline style: padding-right: 17px; to body tag

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I have shiny application (first it open modal dialog then there is tabs wehre one tab, that it's selected by default, have plots) and when I run the app, I've got:

```
<body class="modal-open" style="padding-right: 17px;">
```

I've search whole code using `find | xargs grep` and there are no padding-right in the code.

Why shiny adding that padding and how can I make it stop? I can fix it by adding

```
body {
    padding: 0 !important
}
```

but I want to know why it's happening (maybe there is a reason) so I don't have to fix it in css.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the class .fade or any other class that effects style just try once from modal.